# What is more important CPU or RAM for compiling large software, e.g. bootstrapping gcc?

Tags: memory

I'm looking to buy a new computer soon, and I want a machine for best performance for fast compilation times.

So should I care to get a quad-core CPU with highest GHz I can afford, or should I instead invest into higher speed RAM?

What is your recommendation for what type of RAM should I go for?

Graphics performance doesn't matter, compiling loads of software & running mathematical simulations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say neither. Rather **get a fast SSD hard drive**. Of course you need a proper CPU and amount of RAM as well, but yeah...

Comment: Well, I didn't get an SSD, instead I got 32GB of RAM and compile everything in RAM on tmpfs.... even faster than SSD =)

Comment: Well, that's kind of the same idea :p

Comment: I disagree.  I got an SSD drive for my laptop and it made little difference in compilation speed.  On the other hand, getting a new computer with almost triple the CPU speed and only 4GB vs 6GB on the SSD machine made compiling almost 3 times as fast.  http://www.anandtech.com/show/2829/25 finds no noticeable compiler speed improvement with an SSD while http://blog.hypercomplex.co.uk/index.php/2010/06/ssd-compiler-benchmark/ finds 23% improvement.  It seems logical to me that if you have enough memory, compiling involves very little disk usage.

Comment: Another thought is it's possible some compilers use lots of temp files to compile rather than memory, in which case an SSD or ramdisk would help the most.  However, I wouldn't expect modern compilers to be engineered that way now that memory is cheap and big and the system handles paging it to disk when it runs low.  Using XCode 3.2.6 (based on gcc 3 or 4), SSD had little benefit.

Comment: An SSD makes a considerable difference on large projects/solutions that heavily utilize file copying/moving. I haven't used RAM tmpfs-style, personally, but I have heard good things about it. For smaller projects, it's probably fine. For huge ones? It could be insufficient.

Comment: It makes sense that an SSD doesn't help for projects that aren't huge. For decades, every OS has had a disk cache. After the first time you compile, all the source code is going to be in the kernel's disk cache in RAM, so compiling doesn't need to read anything from disk. And when the compiler/linker writes output files, they go into the kernel's disk cache too. Programs don't have to wait on the drive to write the data so the speed of the drive doesn't matter (unless the disk cache gets full with a huge project).

Comment: Hi from the year 2022!  I upgraded to a new Ryzen 7 CPU and DDR4 RAM.  But the biggest compile time improvement came when I added a M.2 SSD to the motherboard, replacing my SATA SSD.  This cut compile time by over a half for a large .Net solution

Answer (score 7):

Probably RAM will give you a bigger bang for the buck.  Compiling, especially large applications, is very I/O intensive, and having more RAM means you can save more time paging to and from disk.  Most CPUs today, especially if you go with a cheap quad-core, will provide plenty of CPU power for your compiling, but having the RAM will help with the data going back and forth.

On 2nd thought, it sort of depends on your math simulations and build processes.  Are they parallelizable?  If not, adding more cores won't really do anything to speed it up, although the new Intel chips (Core i7) are quite fast on a per-core basis.

Comment: what does compiling have to do with disk ?

Answer (score 4):

For your computations, your processor is by far most important.

The compilation will stress both your processor and RAM.

I think your most cost effective solution would be to get the best CPU you can afford, and preferably a Quad core.
With RAM being as cheap as it is (DDR3 is now as cheap as DDR2), you can easily plug in as much RAM as you need for little coin (16 GB of DDR3 for $180 on newegg ... I realize that is overkill, just trying to demonstrate how cheap it is). So I would invest as much as I can afford on a quality CPU as possible.

Comment: Spending more money to get a faster CPU is good advice. But not spending more money to get more cores. GCC does all its compilation in a single thread, so it never uses more than one core.

Comment: @Isaac Yes, but the build system can usually spawn multiple gcc jobs simultaneously, eg `make` with the `-j` option. Also, I believe llvm can or will be able to compile a single file using multiple threads.

Comment: @Wallacoloo OK, you can *sometimes* get a little extra speed when you have files that are parallel in the dependency graph. Still, I believe that extra cores are a pretty minor factor when it comes to speeding up a build. Hard to tell, since extra cores are a standard feature in newer CPUs that *do* speed things up just by clocking faster. If you want to demonstrate that I'm wrong, try doing a big compile with and without -j.

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch Actually on large code bases it matters *alot*. On our codebase compilation time is reduced almost linearly with `distcc` (`make -j8` (locally) up to  `make -j30` (distributed over the network))

Comment: speaking of `-j`, what about buying a whole bunch of [darn cheap but still usable laptop motherboard-with-CPU](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=laptop+motherboard) parts, insert DRAM then fire up `distcc`s headlessly?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say get loads and loads of RAM and use ramdisks for temporary storage. This will dramatically increase speed of compilation. A fast multi-core CPU would be fine too, but I think that you'd benefit more from lots of ram. Take a look at [this](http://sparc86.wordpress.com/2009/05/21/optimizing-portage-compiling-on-gentoo-with-ccache-shm/) article for some ideas. [Here](http://blog.somekool.net/2007/08/23/optimize-gentoo-with-tmpfs)'s some more information and some more [here](http://apcmag.com/gentoo_tip_for_the_love_of_tmpfs.htm). I think that using RAM will be faster than using SSD, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well graphics could help because a graphics card with a cpu on it can reduce load on the main cpu. CPU power is probably more important then RAM, but the better both are the better off you would be.

Comment: Good point - only if the process could use CUDA cores, which most don't.

Answer (score 0):

due to physical limitations, cores themselves wont get much faster anytime soon, so unless you plan to move into custom silicon investing on faster cpu's wont solve your problem unless parallelization is really going to make some difference but either way many softwares hardly get over 4 cores, I know it because I very often compile my whole system and many times I go look to see resources statistics. Moreover, even if the developers wanted to increase the parallelization it is sometimes chaleging to make it in a good way. Investing on cpu's is good either to increase services performance or if you are doing computations firstly based on data; even if it will influence execution behaviour later on; if your compilations follow some of these patterns then it might be a harder thing to discuss but those are some special cases for build process; that is why for example, on graphical computing more cores are still make some difference. Other then that do what you can to increase I/O as most as you can, it can involve disks, rams and motherboards

Comment: What about it in 2021?
Does a 12 cores CPU add value on compilation times?