# Virtual Machine from Solid State Drive using USB 2.0

Tags: usb, ssd, storage

I want to run a *Virtual Machine*, just like I do from my laptop using an external Solid State Drive.

**Problem is:**
I only have USB 2.0 Ports on my laptop and I need to use this laptop.
The programs I want to run from the VM are CAD programs, so I assume they have a lot of reads and writes.

Is this feasible since the USB speeds might me too slow?
Thanks, I am new to Solid State Drives.

Comment: The SSD is external, since you talk about USB, I presume? Running CAD programs can be painfully slow from external drive. I wouldn't recommend it, although it can be done. USB connection will severely bottleneck your I/O speeds.

Comment: Yes,  I want to use an external drive since my laptop drive is full.

Comment: If you're doing this to get some work done, don't do it. Only do CAD with internal drives. If you're doing this for fun, try it out. See how fast/slow it is. This is my recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same question, just for USB 3.0:

[Can I run a virtual machine from external USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/985596/can-i-run-a-virtual-machine-from-external-usb-drive)

The poster from the above link has updated his post with findings after having used a VM from an external drive on a computer with the following specs:

- Host OS: Windows 10
- Processor: i7 5600U
- RAM: 16 GB

> For anyone who finds this post and wants to know the result: I had some doubts about this pre hand, and I would not recommend this setup for any developer. The boot time is horrible and starting apps like Visual Studio takes at least 3-4 times as long time.
>
> My advice: Only use this solution if you have no alternatives.