# Booting an old laptop HD as VM on another machine

Tags: hard-drive, boot, virtual-machine

I took out a 2.5" hdd off an old laptop. The laptop no longer works; dead battery and won't turn on.

I put the hard drive into an enclosure and plug it into my other machine and it loads up nicely as an external drive.

The drive still has its OSes intact (Win 10 and Ubuntu 20.04). Is it possible to spin up a VM that uses this drive?

What I'm trying to do is create a VM that is basically the old laptop. Is this even possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use physical harddisk in Virtual Box](https://superuser.com/questions/495025/use-physical-harddisk-in-virtual-box)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/985596/can-i-run-a-virtual-machine-from-external-usb-drive

Comment: Either create a linked vmdk as the first link suggest or use a tool such as disk2vhd to create an image of the drive that you can then load in a VM without needing the disk.